# Activity content placement at different place at different launch

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having an application which requires contents in the XML layout (eg:text,button,etc) arranged in different locations, in different launch. I mean that on the first launch, the content will be placed at the top and on the next launch it wiil be placed at the bottom. Likewise anywhere in the whole layout by an automatic choose. How can I implement?

Anyone help me.

Comment: If there aren't too many ways the layout would look simply make a set of layouts files and load them as desired on startup. Anything else than that you should provide more details.